# javax.ejb.TransactionRolledbackLocalException when running against Micro and embedded

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss-arquillian, payara, payara-micro

Currently, I am trying to add testing codes to the [eclipse-ee4j/cargotracker](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/cargotracker) application.

https://github.com/hantsy/cargotracker/

The tests which had been **passed with Payara managed container** failed with Micro and embedded container, there a lot of EJB transaction exception.

```sh
javax.ejb.TransactionRolledbackLocalException: Exception thrown from bean: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

The complete logging can be found there.

https://github.com/hantsy/cargotracker/runs/1789325545

Not sure what is missing in the micro and embedded config, any suggestions?

Add issue: [payara/ecosystem-arquillian-connectors#104](https://github.com/payara/ecosystem-arquillian-connectors/issues/104)

Answer (score 0):

First question, does it pass on Java 8?

Comment: Not tried Java 8, some of my codes is Java 11 based now.